# Why I can't get rid of filesort in a MySQL query that I already build index for

Tags: mysql, indexing, range, filesort

I have a table that has the following schema

**Id**, INT, Primary Key

**QueryId**， INT

**CreatedTime**， DateTime

and I created compound **index(QueryId, CreatedTime)**

How come that when I run 
explain select * from test where queryid in (1,6) order by createdtime desc

I still get the following that has the filesort? Any Idea how could I remove filesort?
**"Using where; Using filesort"**

[image: Explain result]

Comment: MySQL's optimiser has determined that it is faster to sort the file than traverse the index _for this query_. If the query is different, or the number of rows in the table are different, MySQL may choose to do something else. Let it do its job - it's almost certainly better at it than you or me.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually built an index that can be used for that query.

An index can only be used for lookups and sorting from the leftmost column toward the right.  As soon as something non-useful is encountered, the rest of the index is ignored.

You didn't post the output of your `EXPLAIN` but I suspect that if the index is being examined and QueryId is an `INT`, that you'll find `Key_len` = 4 meaning that only the leftmost 4 bytes (QueryId) are useful to the optimizer.

An index on (QueryId,CreatedTime) to pluck records by QueryId, and sort them by CreatedTime if and only if you are selecting a *single* value for QueryId.  When you do that, the index will return the rows matching that QueryId, already sorted by CreatedTime, and the optimizer realizes this.

Conversely, if you look for multiple values of QueryId, the rows returned by the index are returned sorted by QueryId and *then* by CreatedTime within each group of QueryId... so the further filesort is required because the CreatedTime values are essentially sorted in no useful order.  If you `ORDER BY` QueryId, CreatedTime, the filesort should go away, of course, but that's presumably not what you want.

An index on (CreatedTime,QueryId) won't help either, because the QueryId isn't at the left, and unless there are a very small number of rows, the server could pull the rows pre-sorted by CreatedTime, but it would have to scan all of the rows to find matching values for QueryId.

In short, you can't *fully* index for a query like that, and `Using filesort` isn't something that can always be avoided.

Comment: Hi Michael, I added the explain result image to original question, please take a look. I found several places online that has the same situation like me and they used the same way I did and claimed to take effect